# Unable to find model and context class files while using Database first approach

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, edmx

I am new to stackoverflow and for .Net MVC 3 as well.

I am building a MVC 3 web-application in .Net by using database first approach. I created the .edmx file through which Visual Studio has generated the model class and context class files automatically.

Now I want to put some validations in my application, but I am unable to locate the auto generated model classes in the "Models" folder. Though I am able to put the validations in designer.cs file of my .edmx file, where the public partial class appears for my applications "UserDetails" table.

Please clarify, that how can I locate those auto-generated model class files, or tell me if the approach which I tried is a good practice to put the validations inside the designer.cs file of my .edmx file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-generated model class files are located in .designer.cs file. These are generated as partial class and should separate out business logic by creating your own partial class. Otherwise, autogeneration will override your code when regenerate the class from model.

One advice, if you are approaching Entity Framework, DbContext and Code First (POCO) are the first features you should consider. And DbContext is much simpler to use than ObjectContext and will serve the most common development needs.

If you are new with EF, follow the walkthrough from ado.net team which is using with DbContext. (EF 4.1 Model & Database First Walkthrough).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

*("Models" folder in MVC is actually view models and have to create yourself base on the view.)*

Comment: Yes it helped me I generated the model classes, but I got stucked on a few errors. It is giving an error: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MB.Models.MB_UserDetails>' does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MB.Models.MB_UserDetails>' could be found

Comment: It is not recognizing the .AddObject(), .ObjectStateManager() and the .DeleteObject()

Comment: DbContext don't have these methods, these are ObjectContext methods. Instead you can use such as .Add() ,.Remove() methods. Let me advice to this series to better understand about using DbContext. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx)

Comment: Or, if you still want to use feature of ObjectContext, you can use this way. (mydbcontext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

Answer (score 0):

You need to create models on basis of how you want to render views and validations also goes there (Also you can say ViewModel section).It is not good practice to put validations inside designer.cs file.

The best practice to make separation in MVC using [S#arp Lite Architecture](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2011/11/11/s-arp-lite-the-basicss.aspx)